# Is there a more elegant way of getting permutations with replacement in python?

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, python-itertools, discrete-mathematics

I currently want all permutations of a set of elements with replacement.

Example:

```
elements = ['a', 'b']

permutations with replacement = 

[('a', 'a', 'a'),
 ('a', 'a', 'b'),
 ('a', 'b', 'a'),
 ('a', 'b', 'b'),
 ('b', 'a', 'a'),
 ('b', 'a', 'b'),
 ('b', 'b', 'a'),
 ('b', 'b', 'b')]
```

The only way I have been able to do this is so far is with `itertools.product` as follows:

```
import itertools as it

sample_space = ['a', 'b']

outcomes = it.product(sample_space, sample_space, sample_space)
list(outcomes)
```

I am just wondering if there is a better way to do this as it obvious that this can get unwieldy and error prone as the sample space and required length gets larger

was expecting to find something along the lines of `itertools.permutations(['a', 'b'], length=3, replace=True)` maybe?

I tried `itertools.permutations` but the only arguments are `iterable`, and `r` which is the length required.

The output for the above example using `it.permutations(sample_space, 3)` would be an empty list `[]`

Comment: You're going to have to explain how a set with two element becomes permutations in which each set has three elements. Because that's not how permutation works.

Comment: My bad guys. colab doesn't give me the entire docs. @Samwise thanks for pointing out repeat is a kwarg, thats prob why i didnt catch it (at)Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans ofc you are right, i was not using the correct mathematical definition of permutation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sampling with replacement, what you get is by definition not a permutation (which just means "rearrangement") of the set. So I wouldn't look to the `permutations` function for this. `product` is the right thing; e.g. `itertools.product(['a','b'], repeat=3)`.

Note that if you sample from a two-element set with replacement N times, then you have effectively created an N-digit binary number, with all the possibilities that go with it. You've just swapped in 'a' and 'b' for 0 and 1.

Comment: Thanks! Yes you re right, I didn't understand "rearrangement" and mistook it for "arrangement" instead, thanks for pointing that out. I am not entirely sure how your second point applies directly to this problem but I get it in general. Also the idea was to be able to go beyond just two-element sets as well.. Thanks a bunch tho!

Comment: My point is that if you sample [a,b] 3 times, there are 2\*\*3=8 possibilities - the same as the number of 3-bit binary numbers. If you sample [a,b,c] 5 times, there are 3\*\*5=243 possibilities - the same as 5-digit ternary numbers. And so on. You could enumerate the possibilities just by counting.